# Did Allah tell the name of those munafiqeen?

Tags: quran, tafseer, seerah

Allah said :

> There are some who say: “We believe in Allah and in the Last Day,” while in fact they do not believe.
> (2:8)

Did Allah tell the prophet(PBUH) the name of those disbelievers?

Comment: They are the hypocrites.

Comment: Hypocrites show they believe in Allah but they don't do it from heart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, The prophet pbuh even informed hazrat Hudhaifa R. A about the hypocrite list. He was advised by the prophet pbuh to not disclose the list.  There is a wisdom behind not disclosing the names i.e. they may get reformed and become believer if they are not publicly shamed.

> After Muhammad (sal)'s death, the Khalifah often sought his advice
> concerning their activities but he remained tight-lipped. Umar (rali),
> during his Khilafat was only able to find out indirectly who the
> hypocrites were by monitoring Hudhayfah’s attendance at the funeral
> prayer following the death of a Muslim. If Hudhayfah did not attend
> Umar (rali) refrained from performing the funeral prayer for that
> person. Once Umar (rali) asked Hudhayfah if any of his governors was
> a munafiq. Hudhayfah told him that one was but declined to inform
> whom. Hudhayfah later said that shortly after their conversation Umar
> (rali) dismissed the person as if he had been guided to him.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hudhayfah_ibn_al-Yaman